# SQLite not storing/retrieving database

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, uwp

I've got a Windows 10 UWP application written in C#. I'm using SQLite to store my data locally. The issue I'm experiencing is that the file is never saved and/or retrieved using this code. It should work, but I can't find out what's wrong.

dbExists always evaluates to false, so what am I missing here?

```
private SQLiteConnection localConn;
private string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "myDatabase.db");

public async void DBInit()
{
    bool dbExists = false;
    try
    {
        var store = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(dbPath);
        dbExists = true;
    }
    catch { dbExists = false; }
    if (!dbExists)
    {
        using (localConn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath))
        {
            // Create table
            localConn.CreateTable<MyTable>();
        }
    }
    else // CURRENTLY NOT FIRING!!
    {}
}
```

Comment: The only way for `dbExists` to be `false` in this code snippet is, if `GetFileAsync` throws an exception. What exception are you catching (and swallowing)?

Comment: How did you include your `myDatabase.db` in your project? And in which project in your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using below code to create and access database file:

```
StorageFile notesFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(dbPath, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

This will create new file if it does not exists and retrieve it when it is already created.

Please check my blog article to see more about UWP Data Storage:
https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/23/universal-windows-10-apps-data-storage/

Comment: Marking this as the answer. I was assuming SQLite managed the file creation itself. This is confirmed working, thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing this important piece of code:

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("mydatabase.sqlite");
```

Do that first, then create a connection instance referencing the (now) created file.

Also, I'd suggest that you name the db with the .sqlite extension, so that the rest of the team and incoming devs, when then look at the db file artifact, can immediately tell that this is an sqlite database.

EDIT:
The method is a static method. So you would use it like this...

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace sqlite_sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("sample.db");
        }
    }
}
```

The following will **not** work:

```
var conn = SQLiteConnection(...);
conn.CreateFile(dbPath);  //<-- static methods can't be invoked at the instance level...
```

Comment: Turns out there wasn't a method for CreateFile with the SQLite connection. However, I understand the gist. I definitely took your advice on the .sqlite extension in the filename. Good call, thank you.

Comment: It's a static method, not an instance method... maybe that is the problem?