# SQLite on Windows 10 mobile not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, uwp

I want to create this SQLite database for my app, I get this error everytime I try.

An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.dll but was not handled in user code

I have SQLite for uwp installed and I added SQLite for universal app (windows) platform added to the references.

It doesn;t happen on Windows Desktop, just an issue with mobile.

```
private string _dbPath = string.Empty;
    public string DbPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_dbPath))
            {
                _dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Storage.sqlite");
            }

            return _dbPath;
        }
    }

    public SQLiteConnection DbConnection => new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DbPath);
```

Comment: Using SQLite in Windows 10 Universal apps

 http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/

Comment: Please also check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731158/sqlite-not-storing-retrieving-database/37732966#37732966

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have SQLite for uwp installed and I added SQLite for universal app (windows) platform added to the references.
>   It doesn;t happen on Windows Desktop, just an issue with mobile.

According to the code you provided above, you're using SQLite.Net-PCL NuGet Package for SQLite.

I have reproduced the issue when I use SQLite.Net-PCL NuGet Package for SQLite and **only add** "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform" to the reference. The code works fine on local machine but failed on the Mobile Emulator and my Windows Phone.

Base on my research, the SDK "**SQLite for Universal Windows Platform**" depends on SDK "**Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps**".

So we may need to add **both** "SQLite for Universal Windows Platform and "Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps" to the reference when using SQLite.Net-PCL NuGet Package for SQLite.

If only "**SQLite for Universal Windows Platform**" is added, we will get the following warning:

> The SDK "SQLite.UWP.2015, Version=3.13.0" depends on the following SDK(s) "Microsoft.VCLibs, version=14.0", which have not been added to the project or were not found. Please ensure that you add these dependencies to your project or you may experience runtime issues. You can add dependencies to your project through the Reference Manager.

After adding both the two references, the warning disappeared and the issue got fixed.

Comment: I will try it and let you know, Thanks for the quick response.